# Gcloud images page not displaying properly in firefox

Tags: website, firefox, gcloud

Probably just me, but when I went to start our gcloud instance this morning the start/stop/edit icons disappeared when I tried to click on them. I'm using the web interface using firefox on Linux.   Instance started 100% with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like a memory issue with your browser.

Try to clear your browser cache, do not have many other things open at the same time, and possibly try incognito mode.

It might also be caused by some extension/plugin that might be interfering.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it "magically" started working again, not sure what it was tbh